# Showing that range of a map is closed

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Let there exists a positive square root of $T^{*}T$. Let us call it $P$. Then is it true that range of $P$ is a closed subspace of $H$? How can I show that?

Otherwise how an I show that $H$ is direct sum of range of $P$ and its orthogonal complement?

Should I show that $P$ is a projection? For that, I will have to show that $P$ is self-adjoint and idempotent. But I can't see $P$ being idempotent.

Please help

Comment: Consider the map $T:\ell^2(\Bbb N)\to\ell^2(\Bbb N)$, $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\mapsto (2^{-n}x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$. This map is positive hence equal to the root of $T^*T$. However it doesn't have a closed range.